# Почему NavigationDrawer не реагирует на нажатия?

Tags: java, android

Добавил в приложение `NavigationDrawer` в `onCreate()` добавил код инициализации

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

имплементировал `implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

и переопределил слушатель

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.e(MY_LOG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        Log.e(MY_LOG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ActivityAbout.class);
        startActivity(aboutIntent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

В слушателе поставил логи, но при нажатии они не пишутся в логах и ничего при нажатии не происходит.

В чем может быть дело?

Попробовал так добавить слушатель, но тоже не реагирует

```
drawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = v.getId();
            Log.e(MY_LOG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
                Log.e(MY_LOG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ActivityAbout.class);
                startActivity(aboutIntent);
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не повесили этот слушатель на NavigationView. Метод есть, но он никогда и никем не вызывается.

Comment: Странно... метод drawer.setOnClickListener(); принимает как параметр `onClickListener()`... А я делал по примеру в котором переопределяется именно `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` ...

Comment: Добавил в вопрос описание... Там добавил `onClickListener()`, но тоже не реагирует...

Comment: Слушатель надо вешать на навигейшнвью а не на дровер

Comment: Точно, спасибо)) Это моя не внимательность...